# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{}'. .ts(7053) VUEJS

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I know there are multiple questions of this type, but I tried almost everything and I am still getting this error.
I am working in a **vue project**.
I have defined my data as follows:

```
data(){
    return{
      nodes: {},
      edges:{},
      nextNodeIndex: 0,
      nextEdgeIndex: 0,
      selectedNodes: [],
      selectedEdges: [],
      graph: ref<vNG.Instance>() 
    }
  }
```

Now inside a method I am writing a function to addNode

```
 addNode() {
      const nodeId = this.nextNodeIndex
      this.nodes[nodeId] = {
        name: String(nodeId),
        size: 16,
        color: "blue",
        label: true
      }
```

the line `this.nodes[nodeId]` is giving the error  `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{}'.`.
Most of the solutions I found were telling to define the dict as `const dict = {key:string}` but since I am defining the nodes in `data` I can not use const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly type the return type of `data`:

```
data(): { nodes: ..., ... } {

}
```

But that would mean you would have to write a lot of types that TypeScript could've inferred.

I'd settle for an assertion instead:

```
nodes: {} as { [key: number]: { name: string; size: number; ... } },
```

And maybe even for `edges`:

```
edges: {} as { [key: number]: ... },
```

However, seeing that the keys are numbers, you might want to consider using an array instead of an object.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to annotate both types and initial values without declaring anything twice is to use a barebones class for data:

```
class Data {
  // TODO: Fill in correct types instead of `unknown`
  nodes: Record<number, unknown | undefined> = {};
  edges: Record<number, unknown | undefined> = {};
  nextNodeIndex = 0;
  nextEdgeIndex = 0;
  selectedNodes: unknown[] = [];
  selectedEdges: unknown[] = [];
  graph = ref<vNG.Instance>() 
}
```

And then in your data method return an instance:

```
data() {
  return new Data();
}
```

This is slightly misleading as you don't want to actually use this class as a class outside of that nor add methods to it, but it is the least verbose way. It's handy so long as you don't misuse it.